# Como usar GOTO em C para implementar automatos finitos?

Tags: c, goto

É a minha primeira vez utilizando `goto` em programação e eu fiz um código simples aqui pra tentar implementar o automato (deve ter modos muito melhores), porém meu código está travando na hora de executar, não sei se é uma má utilização do GOTO por minha parte, poderiam me dar uma ajuda?

Se alguém tiver alguma dica de como eu posso melhorar minha implementação, também agradeceria muito.

Segue o automato:

<kbd>[image: imagem]</kbd>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char str[80];
int count = 0, erro =0;
printf ("\nType your data entry: ");
scanf ("%79s",str);
int i;
int tam= strlen(str);   
printf("%d", tam);
printf("\nSTRING LIDA: ");

for (i =0; i<tam; i++){
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}



i=0;

goto Q0;


Q0:
    if (i == tam){
        printf("\n\nERROEstado q0 nao e final\n\n");
        erro++;
        goto FINAL;
    }
    if(str[i] == 'a'){
        goto Q1;
        i++;
    }
    if (str[i] == 'b'){
        goto Q2;
        i++;    
    }

Q1:
    if (i == tam){
        printf("\n\nERROEstado q1 nao e final\n\n");
        erro++;
        goto FINAL;
    }
    else if(str[i] == 'a'){
        goto Q0;
        i++;
    }
    else if (str[i] == 'b'){
        goto Q3;
        i++;    
    }

Q2:
    if (i == tam){
        printf("\n\nERROEstado q2 nao e final\n\n");
        erro++;
        goto FINAL;
    }
    else if(str[i] == 'a'){
        goto Q3;
        i++;
    }
    else if (str[i] == 'b'){
        goto Q0;
        i++;    
    }   

Q3:
    if (i == tam){
        goto FINAL;
    }
    else if(str[i] == 'a'){
        goto Q2;
        i++;
    }
    else if (str[i] == 'b'){
        goto Q1;
        i++;    
    }   


FINAL:
    if(erro == 0){
        printf("\n\nEntrada aceita!\n\n");
    }
    else if(erro > 0){
        printf("\n\nERRO: Entrada não aceita\n\n");
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        goto Q3;
        i++;
```

Os teus `i++` nunca vao ser executados, pois estao depois do `goto`

Comment: O retardo eh grande aqui. Obrigado! nao tinha percebido

Comment: Apesar de parecer um problema bobo, eu acho muito interessante esta pergunta e resposta, pois é uma coisa que muitos confundem e ambos vão ajudar outras pessoas ;) +1 pros dois.